# check all button is rendering to the 1st page when i am selecting that in 2nd page(pagination )

Tags: visualforce, javascript, pagination

I have one page where i am searching for contacts.There the result i am getting and i have given pagination for that.to perform any action on those contacts i am using check box.One select all check box is also there.By using that whenever i am selecting select all in the 1st page it is working fine,But whenever i am going to the 2nd page and clicking on the select all check box this is rendering to the 1st page though the 2nd page contacts are getting selected but the render is happening to the 1st page.

Below is my code:
vf page:

```
function checkAll(cb) {
    var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++) {
        if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("theCheckbox")!=-1) {
            inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<c:pageblocktableenhanceradv targetPbTableIds="pbt" 
                             paginate="true" 
                             pageSizeOptions="200,100,50,25" 
                             defaultPageSize="200" 
                             enableExport="true"/>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"  id="pbt" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <apex:inputCheckbox >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                    action="{!GetSelected}" 
                                    onsubmit="checkAll(this)" 
                                    rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox> </th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapContactList}" var="c"  >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.IsAllSelected}" id="theCheckbox">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                        action="{!GetSelected}" 
                                        rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td>{!c.con.Name}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat >
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Visualforce Page: 
    { <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pg">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="w">
            <apex:facet name="footer"><b>Total Number of records:<h5 style="color:green;font-size:30px;">{!count}</h5></b></apex:facet>
           <apex:column > 
               <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allBool}">
                       <apex:actionSupport reRender="pg" action="{!selectAll}" event="onchange"/>
                   </apex:inputCheckbox>
               </apex:facet>
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.checked}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column value="{!w.emp.Name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!w.emp.Type}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!del}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>}
```

Comment: mind adding an explanation? code dump answers dont tend to be very useful, please explain how and why your code should work.